# Filtering results of an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, react-native

im making an app using react-native and i am getting an array from an api.  It has multiple objects in it like the one below I am trying to filter all the objects into categories.

```
Object {
"artists": Array [
  "A",
  "J",
  "At",
],
"average_user_rating": 4,
"categories": Array [
  Object {
    "id": "KUBdKCFGwV",
  },
  Object {
    "id": "ZTNeo8TEIO",
  },
  Object {
    "id": "O0ogwzULe8",
  },
],
"description": "", 
 },
```

im trying to filter it using the below code but i have been unsucsesful

```
    category = "KUBdKCFGwV"
        const filterCate = (category) => {
            return results.filter(result => {
                 if (result.categories.includes(category)) return result.categories;
        })

    };
```

Comment: Are you calling `filterCate()`?

Comment: Please @Anthony show the console error

Comment: FYI, `filter()` only cares whether the callback function returns a truthy or falsey value. You can just do `return result.categories.includes(category)`, you don't need an `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `categories` property is an array of objects, you need to compare their `id` properties. You can use the `some()` method to test if any of the categories match the desired one.

```
const filterCate = (category) => results.filter(result => result.categories.some(cat => cat.id == category));
```

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to filter an object, which the filter function can't do. Try filtering `results.categories`, and check to see if the `category id` matches the `filterCate` parameter:

```js
const results = {
    "artists": [
      "A",
      "J",
      "At",
    ],
    "average_user_rating": 4,
    "categories": [
      {
        "id": "KUBdKCFGwV",
      },
      {
        "id": "ZTNeo8TEIO",
      },
      {
        "id": "O0ogwzULe8",
      },
    ],
    "description": "",
};

const category = "KUBdKCFGwV"
const filterCate = (category) => {
  return results.categories.filter(cats => {
    if (cats.id.includes(category)) return cats.id;
  })
};

console.log(filterCate(category));
```

Comment: The question says he's getting an array of objects, not a single object.

Comment: @Barmar I guess I don't understand the question then. The categories param is also an array of objects.

Comment: It says "It has multiple objects in it like the one below".

Comment: @Barmar but he also says "I am trying to filter all the objects into categories," and categories is an array of objects within the objects themselves. So I have no idea what he is asking for.

Comment: Seems to me that OP tries to filter categories array within the object.

Comment: He wants to get all the containing objects that have the specified category.